# Strange behaviour

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following script which works kind of...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // add or remove from favorites
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() { 
        if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'favorite.aspx',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { ID:$(this).attr("id"), State:"1" }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'favorite.aspx',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { ID:$(this).attr("id"), State:"0" }
            });
        }
    }); 

    // search on keyup
    $(".txtSearchBox").keyup(function() 
    { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search.aspx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { strPhrase:$(".txtHeaderSearch").val() },
            success: function(results) 
            { 
                $("#divSearchResults").empty(); 
                $("#divSearchResults").append(results); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When the page loads for the first time after clearing browser cache, favorites function works fine and so does the search function.  However, after loading the page after a page refresh, if I perform a search first, then try to tag a favorite, the favorite will not get inserted into the database, I have to click the reload browser button, then add a favorite.

Why is this happening?

Comment: you have a syntax error at " url: favorite.aspx',"  you let out the single quote before the favorite.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `live()` as you are trying to act on stuff in the dom which you are inserting using ajax.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Live is an answer, but I've had problems with change event with live and Internet Explorer, at least with select fields. I've solved the problem by using the livequery plugin.

[jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) should also work if you don't want to install plugins.